# How to remove all spaces at the end of strings in a text file in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, sed, awk

I have file named a.txt and it contains strings but got some additional spaces at the end 
`cat -vet a.txt` displays

```
ab cd^M$
abcdefg ^M$ //there is a space at the end
aaaaaaa^M$
bbbbbbb^I^M$ //there is a tab at the end
xyz^M$
ab cc ^M$ //there is a space at the end
hello^M$
help me^M$ 
to solve ^M$ //there is a space at the end
this problem^M$
^M$
^M$
```

So how to remove the space at the end of the string

Tried using this sed command but failed

```
sed -i -E 's/ *$//' a.txt
```

Comment: Start by removing the ^M by `dos2unix` or `fromdos`.

Comment: Sorry I did not get it I am beginner in text-processing

Comment: Run either of the commands on the file before doing anything else.

Comment: I have no problem with carriage return ^M$ but with this " " at the end of the sting or ^I

Answer (score 0):

`^M` is a MSWin line end, so `$` doesn't match at it. If you don't want to remove the carriage returns, you need to match them in the reges, too. Use `\r` for ^M and `\t` for a tab (`^I`):

```
sed -e 's/[\t ]*\r$//'
```

If some lines don't end in a carriage return, make it optional. You'll then need to make the whitespace non-optional, otherwise sed would match an empty string:

```
sed -e 's/[\t ]\+\r\?$//'
# or
sed -E 's/[\t ]+\r?$//'
```

Comment: Using this command tab ^I and ^M was removed but still space exists at the end of the string example ```choroba $``` see there is a space after your name and I want to remove that

Comment: So, unlike in the sample, you don't have `^M` at every line end?

Comment: Yes I dont have ^M(before I had ```choroba[space]^M$``` means this ```choroba ^M$```) but I am having this " "[blank or space] at the end I mean I want ```choroba$```         instead I have ```choroba $``` a blank or space at the end.

Comment: @Kros I've updated the answer.

Comment: thank you only first updated command -e is working not second.I want to explore more on sed so if you can help with some good books or links

Comment: @Kros: What do you mean by "not working"? What OS are you on, what version of sed?

Comment: This worked for me ```sed -e 's/[\t ]\+\r\?$//'```

Comment: And how did the other one with `-E` *not* work? What OS are you on, what version of sed?

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`sed -e '/[[:space:]]\+$/s///'`
or
`sed -Ee '/[[:space:]]+$/s///'`
meaning:

> “If any spacing characters are at the end of a line, strip them.”

ASCII CR (^M) is a spacing character (as are LF, FF, space, TAB).